# Django modelform: Create new related object

Tags: python, django, modelform

I've been searching stack overflow and google for a solution for over an hour now, and I can't seem to find something that, in my opinion, should be easy to obtain (as it's a common use case).
I've checked this thread, and a few others, but I haven't been able to find a real, easy solution:
[Django modelform: is inline adding related model possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207464/django-modelform-is-inline-adding-related-model-possible)

Anyway, say I have a model with three related entities, two foreign keys and a many-to-many related class. Now, I have a ModelForm which displays these in comboboxes and lists, but what I need is that "+" button next to these elements (as seen in the admin interface).

I want the plus to take me to a new form, for that particular entity, allow me to submit the new information, create the database entry, take me back to my original form and have the newly added entity selected in the combobox. I'm really hoping the django `ModelForm` `Meta` class has an attribute that I can't seem to find which enables exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a django question.

This has to do with presentation of a particular widget in an html document, and that is governed by either the HTML markup, CSS, or javascript.

Django is a server side application and is primarily responsible for creating a valid http response and receiving a valid http request (of course, there is a lot that happens in the interim and that is why django is so big) but it's not a "one toolkit to kill them all" app.

I think you want to look at bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/
Jquery UI: http://jqueryui.com/

Or some combination of the two.

You can also just mark up the document yourself with a stock img or something.

However, if you want to do it exactly how the admin does it, just go into django.contrib.admin and examin the code to figure out how the django developers did it. I believe they are just using Jquery UI and some manual markup to accomplish that.